# How to round edges on mesh

Tags: edges

I'm trying to get round edges on my mesh but using inset extrude or subdivision and bevel don't seem to do the trick this is what i have[image]

[image]

and this is what i want

Comment: You tried using crease when you did subdivision?

Comment: No, i will definitely try though

Comment: it works for smoothing out the mesh in general but i get horrible artifacts on the side of my mesh and it's not smoothing it in the way i want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
press smooth on left panel to get this:

[image]

add supporting loops (ctrl + r) to sharpen the edges (the effect will be visible when you will add the subdivision surface modifier)
[image]
selec the upper faces and press "i" to inset them (by doing this you add a supporting loop near the edge of your shape)
[image]
finnaly add the subdivision modifier and increase the number of subdivision in the view panel up to 2 (this modifier smooth the shape but the closer edges are, the sharper is the angle made by those edges)
[image]
the order of the operation (adding edges loop and adding subdivision surface) is not important

Comment: Thank you very much for all the detail i will try it:)

Comment: Thanks this helped alot

Answer (score 1):

Your Mesh normals are reversed, press ctrl + N to fix them while all faces are selected. You can select the edges you want to bevel and ctrl + B them, or you can set a bevel modifier to work based on edge angle. If neither do the trick, try creasing and subdividing

Comment: Thank you ill try this:)

Comment: Clearing my normals seemed to do something however the bevel is still the same as before and i already tried creasing and subdividing